# How to stop the onClick change background or highlight on listView?

Tags: android

My listview right now changes color to orange when clicked how do I stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should have to do is add:

```
android:listSelector="@null"
```

to your ListView in your XML.

-Dan

Comment: Can you post the XML snippet of your ListView?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your list view:

```
  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: I believe that is for the background color to describe the background to which the list is being placed into

Comment: i too had the problem and i tried it and it worked fine for me have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

in your custom list adapter put
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); or any color you want